# Calling constructor of a template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a container class which has a pre allocated buffer. I am calling memset() to use pre-allocated memory to create my objects. Since I am not using new, the constructor is not called.

Here is a simplified version of the add function

```
 template<typename T>
 T* CContainer<T>::Add()
 {
memset(&m_pBuffer[index],0,index);
T* pReturnValue = reinterpret_cast<T*> ( &m_pBuffer[index] );

return pReturnValue;
 }
```

Any way to call the constructor of template class T.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use "placement new". [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new) has a good explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call the constructor of an object in an existing piece of memory use [placement new](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/calling-constructors-with-placement-new/232901023?pgno=2).

In your case add this line right before the return statement:

```
new (pReturnValue) T;
```

To destroy the instance, call the destructor explicitly:

```
pReturnValue->~T();
```

Comment: Thanks guys, is there a way to call the destructor when removing an object and reassigning its memory?

Comment: @Codesmith: added edit for destructor call. If you find this post acceptable, please mark it as an asnwer to your question.